# usb flash size decreased from 32 Gb to 5 Mb (after trying ubuntu)

Tags: windows-8, usb-flash-drive

I've used my 32 Gb USB flash to try ubuntu. Now I don't want ubuntu anymore so I formated my USB flash. But size of it now 5 Mb instead of 32 Gb (likely this is because ubuntu uses two partitions and first one is very small)

In Windows I've found that the rest of the USB just "Unallocated" but I can't "Shrink".

[image]

How can I have entire flash back? "Format" doesn't help.

Comment: Did you use the official SD card formatter? https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Comment: thanks, i followed these instructions http://www.supertalent.com/datasheets/Resetting%20USB%20drive%20using%20Windows%20Diskpart-V1.pdf (page 10-13) and it works fine.